# injectIntl expects class with props that includes `intl`

Tags: typescript, react-intl

I am having a problem with class `React.ComponentClass` type class.

My TypeScript version is 2.4.2 -

My component is this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { injectIntl, InjectedIntlProps } from 'react-intl';

interface IBlahProps extends InjectedIntlProps {

}

class BlahBase extends React.Component<IBlahProps> {

}

const Blah = injectIntl(BlahBase);

export default Blah;
```

This all works fine.

But when I consume this component like this:

```
render() {
  return <Blah />
}
```

The `<Blah />` gets underlined saying screenshot below:

> [ts] Type '{}' is not assignable to type
>
> 'Readonly'.   Property 'intl' is missing in type '{}'.
>
> import Blah

How can I understand why this is the case, and how can I fix it? I don't want to have to do `<Blah intl={intl} />`.

The `index.d.ts` for `injectIntl` looks like this:

```
function injectIntl<P>(component: ComponentConstructor<P & InjectedIntlProps>, options?: InjectIntlConfig):
        React.ComponentClass<P> & { WrappedComponent: ComponentConstructor<P & InjectedIntlProps> };
```

I'm able to fix this by changing the interface from extending `InjectedIntlProps` to a type like this:

```
type IBlahProps = InjectedIntlProps & {

}
```

But I have no idea why extending `InjectedIntlProps` doesn't fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

maybe there is a typo?

I just tested your example with typescript `2.9.2`, works well for me:

```
import { injectIntl, InjectedIntl } from "react-intl";

interface IBlahProps  {
  intl: InjectedIntl;
}

class BlahBase extends React.Component<IBlahProps> {

}

const Blah = injectIntl(BlahBase);
```

Please notice `const Blah` not `class Blah`

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks I fixed mistake in question, it was just in question I made typo. I tested again and am getting same error :( My typescript version is 2.5. I upvoted for your effort. :)